# cumsum and if-condition in dplyr in r not giving expected output

Tags: r

I was trying to solve the below problem with dplyr and managed to make some progress, but I'm facing few problems at some point.

**Problem Statement**

In each of the groups(grouped by ID), if the same ID's current HID and previous HID are different and the Interval < 30, then the Penalty column should show the value from Amount. In all other conditions, it should show 0(the other conditions could mean either the HIDs being same, or HIDs different but Interval >= 30 )

**Data**

```
"ID","DaysToEvent","HID","Interval","Amount"
2197560,16369,"011",29,90105
2197560,16494,"121",29,50526
2197560,16509,"121",29,194568
2197560,16569,"001",31,27236
2197560,16577,"128",29,17309
2197578,14447,"001",29,17276
2197578,14468,"021",29,12661
2197578,14489,"001",31,15015
2197578,14517,"001",29,19000
2197578,14517,"02P",29,19001
2197578,14517,"001",31,19002
2197578,14517,"001",29,19003
2197578,14517,"001",29,19004
```

**My code**

```
mycoredata2009 = read.csv('path/to/abovefile.csv')
CumulativeCumulativeCost = 0;
mycoredata2009 = mycoredata2009 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Penalty = ifelse( ((HID != lag(HID)) & Interval < 30) ,Amount,0)) %>% 
    mutate(CumulativeCost=cumsum(as.numeric(Penalty))) %>%
    CumulativeCumulativeCost = cumsum(as.numeric(CumulativeCost)) %>%
    cat(paste("For group with ID==",ID,"CumulativeCost==", CumulativeCost,sep=""))
    mycoredata2009 = as.data.frame(mycoredata2009)
```

**Problems I'm currently facing**

However, there are a couple of problems with the code

1. The Penalty column shows the value of Amount even if the current HID
   and previous HID are the same.(works correctly for the other two
   conditions )
2. The CumulativeCost column which is supposed to be a running cost of
       the Penalty column always shows NA
3. At the end of each group, I want to print the CumulativeCost of that
       group and keep inserting the ID and CumulativeCost of that
       group into a final output data frame
4. I also want to have a variable called CumulativeCumulativeCost
   which, as the name suggests is a running sum of the CumulativeCost
   of each group.

**Received output**

```
   ID DaysToEvent HID Interval Amount Penalty CumulativeCost
1    2197560       16369      011                29  90105      NA             NA
2    2197560       16494      121                29  50526   50526             NA
3    2197560       16509      121                29 194568  194568             NA
4    2197560       16569      001                31  27236       0             NA
5    2197560       16577      128                29  17309   17309             NA
6    2197578       14447      001                29  17276      NA             NA
7    2197578       14468      021                29  12661   12661             NA
8    2197578       14489      001                31  15015       0             NA
9    2197578       14517      001                29  19000   19000             NA
10   2197578       14517      02P                29  19001   19001             NA
11   2197578       14517      001                31  19002       0             NA
12   2197578       14517      001                29  19003   19003             NA
13   2197578       14517      001                29  19004   19004             NA
```

**Expected output**(hand calculated)

```
   ID DaysToEvent HID Interval Amount Penalty CumulativeCost
1    2197560       16369      011                29  90105      NA             NA
2    2197560       16494      121                29  50526   50526          50526
3    2197560       16509      121                29 194568       0          50526
4    2197560       16569      001                31  27236       0          50526
5    2197560       16577      128                29  17309   17309          67835
6    2197578       14447      001                29  17276      NA             NA
7    2197578       14468      021                29  12661   12661          12661
8    2197578       14489      001                31  15015       0          12661
9    2197578       14517      001                29  19000       0          12661
10   2197578       14517      02P                29  19001   19001          31662
11   2197578       14517      001                31  19002       0          31662
12   2197578       14517      001                29  19003       0          31662
13   2197578       14517      001                29  19004       0          31662
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the expected output, after we create the "Penalty" column using the logical condition (`HID!=lag(HID,...)`), change the first observation in the "Penalty" column per each group to "NA", get the `cumsum` of the other rows, and append `NA` to it (`c(NA, cumsum(...)`) to create the "CumulativeCost"

```
 library(dplyr)
 mycoredata2009%>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Penalty= ifelse(HID!=lag(HID, default=0) & Interval<30, Amount, 0), 
              Penalty=ifelse(row_number()==1L, NA, Penalty), 
              CumulativeCost=c(NA, cumsum(Penalty[-1L])))
  #        ID DaysToEvent HID Interval Amount Penalty CumulativeCost
  #1  2197560       16369 011       29  90105      NA             NA
  #2  2197560       16494 121       29  50526   50526          50526
  #3  2197560       16509 121       29 194568       0          50526
  #4  2197560       16569 001       31  27236       0          50526
  #5  2197560       16577 128       29  17309   17309          67835
  #6  2197578       14447 001       29  17276      NA             NA
  #7  2197578       14468 021       29  12661   12661          12661
  #8  2197578       14489 001       31  15015       0          12661
  #9  2197578       14517 001       29  19000       0          12661
  #10 2197578       14517 02P       29  19001   19001          31662
  #11 2197578       14517 001       31  19002       0          31662
  #12 2197578       14517 001       29  19003       0          31662
  #13 2197578       14517 001       29  19004       0          31662
```

Or we could remove the `ifelse`

```
 mycoredata2009 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Penalty=NA^(row_number()==1L)*(HID!=lag(HID, default=0) & 
                  Interval<30)*Amount,
            CumulativeCost=c(NA, cumsum(Penalty[-1L])))
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.9.5
 setDT(mycoredata2009)[, {
  tmp = NA^(1:.N==1L)*(HID!= shift(HID, fill=0) & Interval<30)*Amount
   c(.SD, list(Penalty=tmp, CumulativeCost=c(NA, cumsum(tmp[-1L])))) 
   },ID]

  #1: 2197560       16369 011       29  90105      NA             NA
  #2: 2197560       16494 121       29  50526   50526          50526
  #3: 2197560       16509 121       29 194568       0          50526
  #4: 2197560       16569 001       31  27236       0          50526
  #5: 2197560       16577 128       29  17309   17309          67835
  #6: 2197578       14447 001       29  17276      NA             NA
  #7: 2197578       14468 021       29  12661   12661          12661
  #8: 2197578       14489 001       31  15015       0          12661
  #9: 2197578       14517 001       29  19000       0          12661
 #10: 2197578       14517 02P       29  19001   19001          31662
 #11: 2197578       14517 001       31  19002       0          31662
 #12: 2197578       14517 001       29  19003       0          31662
 #13: 2197578       14517 001       29  19004       0          31662
```